# Form data not passing to PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have what should be a simple form to pass data to a php page. The form is:

```
<form action="php/setlist.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" id="SetListName" />
<input type="hidden" id="newList" name="newList" value="" readonly="readonly" style="border: none;">
<input type="submit" style="width:150px;"><br /><br />
```

and the php is:

```
$SetListSave = $_REQUEST['newList'];
$SetListName= $_REQUEST['SetListName'];

echo $SetListName;
echo $SetListSave;
```

I am getting the newList from the form just fine but the SetListName isn't getting passed. I am a novice with php so I could be missing something basic here, but I am stumped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing `name` attribute in:

```
<input type="text" id="SetListName" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<input type="text" id="SetListName" />
```

with

```
<input type="text" id="SetListName" name ="SetListName"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a 'name' attribute in the form for each input field that you want to read in PHP. So you're code should read:

```
<form action="php/setlist.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" id="SetListName" name="SetListName"/>
<input type="hidden" id="newList" name="newList" value="" readonly="readonly" style="border: none;">
<input type="submit" style="width:150px;"><br /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<input type="text" id="SetListName" name="SetListName" />
```

you have not used `name` attribute